How can I remove the blank line at the start of an HTML document
I am writing an HTML document which just contains a number of images (in several paragraphs as I use some for highlighting). It begins:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>
<img src="..." style="width:44mm;height:63mm;float:left;">
<img src="..." style="width:44mm;height:63mm;float:left;">
<img src="..." style="width:44mm;height:63mm;float:left;">
<img src="..." style="width:44mm;height:63mm;float:left;">
<img src="..." style="width:44mm;height:63mm;float:left;">
<img src="..." style="width:44mm;height:63mm;float:left;">
<img src="..." style="width:44mm;height:63mm;float:left;">

However, whenever I view it in Edge or Firefox there is a blank line before the images. I have tried removing the line breaks in the html source and adding style="margin:0" to the <html>, <body>, and <p> tags (similarly to How to remove the blank lines before and after html pre-formatted text?) but these don't make any difference.
How can I remove this leading blank line? If it matters, I am much more interested in the printed result (where the blank line also appears) than what is shown in a browser.

Different browsers style body/HTML/p/h tags differently  Which is why people often us a CSS reset to clear client styles.  It's not just margins that cause spaces, but also padding.  I would try re-setting both margin and padding to 0 on html, body, p etc.

Have you used the dev tools to inspect your page?  You should inspect every element until you find the one adding the space you are concerned with.

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

Will reset predefined styles of all elements.
